# Flutter Upgrade broke button tranistions, keeping some buttons invisible.

Tags: flutter

Recently I ran a `flutter upgrade`, a button transition I had built with floating actions buttons that used to work correctly, no longer works. The animation hides all the buttons except the last ones. Any ideas on what changes are causing this issue?

[image]

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, v0.5.6-pre.55, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.3)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.0)
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2018.1)
[!] VS Code (version 1.23.1)
[✓] Connected devices (1 available)
```

have a look at a sample project: https://github.com/abarrafo/flutter_button_animation

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
    body: new Container(),
    floatingActionButton: new SingleChildScrollView(
        child: new Container(
            padding: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                0.0,
                _showMenu ? 50.0 : 0.0,
                0.0,
                0.0),
            child: new Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children:
                !_showMenu ? new List()
                    : new List.generate(widget.icons.length, (int index) {
                Widget child = new Container(
                    height: 70.0,
                    width: 56.0,
                    alignment: FractionalOffset.topCenter,
                    child: new ScaleTransition(
                    scale: new CurvedAnimation(
                        parent: _animationController,
                        curve: new Interval(
                            0.0,
                            1.0 - index / widget.icons.length / 2.0,
                            curve: Curves.easeOut
                        ),
                    ),
                    child: index == 2 || index == 3 ? new GestureDetector(
                        onDoubleTap: (){
                        //do stuff
                        },
                        onLongPress: (){
                        //do other stuff
                        },
                        child: new FloatingActionButton(
                        heroTag: index,
                        mini: true,
                        child: new Icon(widget.icons[index]),
                        onPressed: () {
                            //do other stuff
                        },
                        ),
                    ) :
                    new FloatingActionButton(
                        heroTag: index,
                        mini: true,
                        child: new Icon(widget.icons[index]),
                        onPressed: () {
                        //do stuff
                        },
                    )
                    ,
                    ),
                );
                return child;
                }).toList()..add(
                new Opacity(opacity: 0.5,
                    child:  new FloatingActionButton(
                        elevation: 3.0,
                        child: new AnimatedBuilder(
                        animation: _animationController,
                        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
                            return new Transform(
                            transform: new Matrix4.rotationZ(
                                _animationController.value * 0.5 * math.pi),
                            alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                            child: new Icon(_animationController.isDismissed
                                ? Icons.menu
                                : Icons.close),
                            );
                        },
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                        if (_animationController.isDismissed) {
                            setState(() {
                            _showMenu = true;
                            });
                            _animationController.forward();
                        } else {
                            new Timer(new Duration(milliseconds: 500), (){
                            setState(() {
                                _showMenu = false;
                            });
                            });
                            _animationController.reverse();
                        }
                        },
                    )
                ),
                )),
        )
    ),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I ran flutter upgrade again, and it is fixed. My guess is this was a bug introduced in a flutter build and was resolved quickly.